# Receiving an error in my flutter code. The named parameter 'child' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

I am reciving an error with my flutter app.

Here is the error

Error: No named parameter with the name 'child' in Flutter

The error is on line 51 and 62

Im trying to build an app in flutter. Im reciving an error when using child. Im trying to make an elevated button and some text but for both im reciving this error

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Time Attack',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Time Attack'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final player = AudioCache();
            //player.play('musicForapp.mp3');
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Icon(Icons.punch_clock),
        ),
        body: Column(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: const Text(
              "Click the Icon in the bottem left to simulate an alarm",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const TasksPage(),
              ),
            );
          }, //on pressed
          child: const Text("Navigate"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
} //_MyHomePageState

class TasksPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TasksPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TasksPage> createState() => _TasksPageState();
}

class _TasksPageState extends State<TasksPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Tasks'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text(
            "What is 2 x 2?",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
} //_TasksPageState
```

Why am I reciving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because `Column` should have a `children`, not a child.  try this

```html
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('Time Attack'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final player = AudioCache();
            //player.play('musicForapp.mp3');
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          child: const Icon(Icons.punch_clock),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Text(
                "Click the Icon in the bottem left to simulate an alarm",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => const TasksPage(),
                  ),
                );
              }, //on pressed
              child: const Text("Navigate"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  } //widget build
} /
```